# How do I override a convention's cascade rule in fluent nhibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I have two classes

```
public class Document 
{ 
    public virtual int Id { get; set; } 
    public virtual IList<File> Files { get; set; } 
} 
public class File 
{ 
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; } 
    public virtual Document Document { get; set; } 
}
```

with the following convention:

```
public class HasManyConvention : IHasManyConvention 
{ 
    public bool Accept(IOneToManyPart target) 
    { 
        return true; 
    } 
    public void Apply(IOneToManyPart target) 
    { 
        target.Cascade.All(); 
    } 
}
```

and these mapping overrides

```
public class DocumentMappingOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Document> 
{ 
    public void Override(AutoMap<Document> mapping) 
    { 
        mapping.HasMany(x => x.Files) 
            .Inverse() 
            // this line has no effect
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan(); 
    } 
} 

public class FileMappingOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<File> 
{ 
    public void Override(AutoMap<File> mapping) 
    { 
        mapping.References(x => x.Document).Not.Nullable(); 
    } 
}
```

I understand that I need to make an IClassConvention for Document to 
change the cascade behaviour, however I can't get this to work! 
If i do this:

```
public class DocumentConvention : IClassConvention 
{ 
    public bool Accept(IClassMap target) 
    { 
        return target.EntityType == typeof(Document); 
    } 
    public void Apply(IClassMap target) 
    { 
        target.SetAttribute("cascade", "all-delete-orphan"); 
    } 
}
```

I get: "The 'cascade' attribute is not declared."

If i do this:

```
public class DocumentConvention : IClassConvention 
{ 
    public bool Accept(IClassMap target) 
    { 
        return target.EntityType == typeof(Document); 
    } 
    public void Apply(IClassMap target) 
    { 
        target.HasMany<Document, File>(x => x.Files) 
            .Inverse() 
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan(); 
    } 
}
```

Then I get:

```
"Duplicate collection role mapping Document.Files"
```

so i added:

```
mapping.IgnoreProperty(x => x.Files);
```

to my document mapping, but then Files is always empty. 
What am I doing wrong? 
How can I override the cascade rule for a single HasMany relationship? 
Thanks 
Andrew

P.s. Sorry for the cross post with [this](http://groups.google.com/group/fluent-nhibernate/browse_thread/thread/2decca3efff52225) but I need to get this solved asap.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was forever ago (in computer time) and you might have already solved this. In case you haven't or someone else with a similar question sees this, here goes:

I think you need to create a class that implements `IHasManyConvention`. `IClassConvention` modifies an `IClassMap` (the `<class>` element) target. `cascade` is not a valid attribute for `<class>` so that accounts for the first error. On your second attempt, you were re-mapping the collection, resulting in the "duplicate collection" error.

`IHasManyConvention` targets an `IOneToManyPart`, upon which you should be able to call `Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()` or just `SetAttribute("cascade", "all-delete-orphan")` if the former didn't work for some reason.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I missed that you already had a IHasManyConvention. Since you want to override your convention for just one type, you should just change the `Accept` method on your convention for that type. Instead of `return true;`, pull in what you had on your `DocumentConvention`:

```
return target.EntityType == typeof(Document);
```

I believe that `OneToManyPart.EntityType` references the containing entity type (i.e. `Document`).